# Find $P(aX \leq X)$ when $a \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ and $X \sim f_{X}(x)$ and $X \geq 0$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I want to find $P(aX \leq X)$ when $a \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ and $X \sim f_{X}(x)$ is continuous and $X \geq 0$.

I know that if I let $Y = aX$, and assumed that $Y$ and $X$ were independent, I could simply compute the CDF of the ratio distribution. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution

However, in my case, $Y$ and $X$ are clearly not independent. So how can I solve this?

---

Would it just be:

$$P(aX \leq X) = P((a-1)X \leq 0)$$

But what about the fact that $X \geq 0$? Eg. Exponential, Gamma, Chi Squared RVs. Is there something different that I need to do?

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discern the following cases:

- if $a>1$ then $\{aX\leq X\}=\{X\leq0\}$
- if $a=1$ then $\{aX\leq X\}=\Omega$
- if $a<1$ then $\{aX\leq X\}=\{X\geq0\}$

Comment: Okay, I think this makes sense. So then you get your answer from $\{(a-1)X \leq 0\} = \{kX \leq 0\}  = \{X \leq 0\}$ (where $k = (a-1)$) correct?

Comment: It states that in all cases knowledge of the CDF $F=F_X$ is enough. In the first case the answer is $P(X\leq 0)=F(0)$, in the second case the answer is $1$ and in the third case the answer is $1-P(X<0)=1-\lim_{x\to0-}F(x)$. If moreover $F$ is continuous (which is the case here because $X$ has a PDF) then $\lim_{x\to0-}F(x)=F(0)$ so then the answer is the third case is $1-F(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on $a$. If $a\leq 1$ then the answer is $1$ because $aX  \leq X$. If $a>1$ the the answer is $0$ because $P(X\leq 0,X \geq 0)$ =P(X=0)=0$ in view of the fact that distribution is given to be continuous.